# Is there a document describing the design rationale behind Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum-design

- What are the design decissions behind Ethereum?
- Why are storage words 256-bit long?
- Why is Ethereum using the account model and not the UTXO model?
- ...

Is there a document describing these design decissions?

Comment: This document is very useful for understanding Ethereum. I have to admit that I am discovering it today for the first time during the research for an answer. Posting it here as Q&A in the hope you find it useful too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design rationale behind Ethereum is described in Ethereum Wiki:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale